# What bug in first version of game Karateka for Apple 2e cause this game reset in Apple 2c?

Tags: apple-ii, 8-bit-microcomputers, bugs

If I try to start the first version of the game Karateka for Apple IIe on an Apple IIc, the Apple IIc will restart after reading the game from disk after a few seconds. Later versions of Karateka for Apple IIc will work. What is the bug in the first version that caused it not to work with Apple IIc?

Comment: Also consider the possibility that you are using "cracked" versions, which may be faulty, not "first" and "later" versions.

Comment: Can you please link to a version which doesn't work? IIRC, Karateka used boot zero (the Disk II Interface Card ROM) in a way which caused problems for later boot ROMs in the Laser 128 and Apple IIgs.

Comment: Version on disk but I think @dirkt is correct, it is cracked version.  But it still have some bug cause reset on Apple 2c but not Apple 2e. This is a bug I see many years ago.

Comment: It's possible that it included a check of certain ROM locations which differ between the machines.  Choplifter wouldn't boot on a IIe vs II+ for that reason.

Answer (score 3):

For the cracked version the problem was identified [long ago](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.sys.apple2/pf6Op1J2o3Q/C60xILYq1bIJ):

> I have heard that it is only the cracked version of Karateka which has
>   a problem.
>
> The problem is that on every disk access, Karateka takes a copy of the
>   ROM from the Disk II controller card and patches it.  It then uses the
>   patched copy to do the disk I/O.  The resulting code crashes on the
>   IIc and IIgs because the routines in the firmware are in a slightly
>   different location.
>   -- David Empson

The IIgs problem is with the slot 6 "Disk Port" firmware. The problem will not occur if the slot configuration is set to "Your Card" and a Disk II Interface Card is present.